# how to hide react native change image white effect on android

Tags: react-native

I have list of images and want display one image on view on tap next will be displayed. 
when new image url is updated via state it shows a white blur effect only on android not on ios.

```
<TouchableHighlight
      onPress={() => {
        this.contentClick();
       }
      } >
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)'}}>
         <Image
            style={styles.contentImage}
            source={
              this.state.album0data[this.state.currentImageIndex]
            }
            fadeDuration={0}
          />
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

can someone help

Comment: White Effect on Android, is it because you're using TouchableHighLight?
If it really matter to what you see...
You can try using **TouchableWithoutFeedback**.

Comment: this did't worked effect is of  image change not button.

Answer (score 0):

The first check OS with Platform like this:

```
import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 200 : 100,
});
```

and can you tell me you want to show list of image in a Flatlist or just a view?

Comment: I want show one image on screen if user tab next will be displayed no need to flatlist etc

Comment: What do you write in function contentClick? Can you show me your code?

Comment: it's just updating some state values of current image index and next